# Jetty's (7.3.1) Rewrite

Tags: java, http, web, jetty, url-rewriting

As I don't have the source of a Web application, I created another one that would do the necessary verfications before allowing any request to reach the main app.

And since I am using Jetty, I made use of Rewrite.

I successfully intercept HTTP requests intended to reach the app to be protected. But  when the new app redirects to the subject app, I somehow end up in an infinite loop.

Consequently, Jetty blocks the redirection to the url that matches the filter value in the Jetty-Rewrite.xml file.

All that works so far is to be redirected to the verifications forms. I can't move forward.

The two crucial rules in **Jetty-Rewrite.xml**, and cause the problem, look like the following:

```html
<Call name="addRule">
  <Arg>
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteRegexRule">
      <Set name="regex">/destination-app/(.*)</Set>
      <Set name="replacement">/verification-app/</Set>
      <Set name="terminating">false</Set>
    </New>
  </Arg>
</Call>
<Call name="addRule">
  <Arg>
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteRegexRule">
      <Set name="regex">/dummy-path/</Set>
      <Set name="replacement">/destination-app/login.jsp</Set>
      <Set name="terminating">false</Set>
    </New>
  </Arg>
</Call>
```

Basically, that's what I need to do:

[image]

Comment: Need more information.  Can you post the rewrite rule XML you are struggling with?

Comment: Also, [Jetty 7 and Jetty 8 are now EOL (end of life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html)